# Compare one array with a nested array and push value into a new array with same index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, nested-loops

I have 2 arrays

```
const arrayOne = [
 {id: '110'},
 {id: '202'},
 {id: '259'}
];

const arrayTwo = [
 {data: [{value: 'Alpha', id: '001'}]},
 {data: [{value: 'Bravo', id: '202'}]},
 {data: [{value: 'Charlie', id: '110'}]},
 {data: [{value: 'Delta', id: '202'}]}
];
```

I need to create a new array comparing `arrayOne[idx].id` with `arrayTwo[idx].data[idx2].id`

Upon match, I need to create an array pushing **value** (`arrayTwo[idx].data[idx2].value`) to the new array against each index in `arrayOne`.

In this example, I would get `newArray = [null, 'Bravo', null, Delta]`

What I have tried:

```
arrayOne.map(item => ({
   ...item,
   result: arrayTwo.filter(itemTwo => item.data.map(x => x.id).includes(itemTwo.id))
}));
```

and also

```
const newArr = [];
arrayOne.map((item, idx) => {
   if (arrayTwo.filter(itemTwo => itemTwo.data?.map(x => x.id) === item.id)) {
     newArr.push(arrayTwo.data[idx].value);
   } else newArr.push(null);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can map `arrayTwo` and use `.find()` to search for the ID in arrayOne. I also mapped arrayTwo to the inner object to make the second map more concise.

```js
const arrayOne = [
 {id: '110'},
 {id: '202'},
 {id: '259'}
];

const arrayTwo = [
 {data: [{value: 'Alpha',id: '001'}]},
 {data: [{value: 'Bravo',id: '202'}]}, 
 {data: [{value: 'Charlie',id: '777'}]},
  {data: [{value: 'Delta',id: '202'}]}
];

const result = arrayTwo
  .map(obj => obj.data[0])
  .map(obj => (arrayOne.find(v => v.id === obj.id) && obj.value) || null)
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you for your answer. What if `arrayTwo` have multiple matches with `arrayOne` and a different `value` for each object? I have updated the `arrayTwo` in the question to reflect the same. Appreciate your response!

Comment: @Aaron I updated the answer. Because these new requirements are pretty different from the original one, next time, I'd say it'd be better to post a new question, and link it in the comments here for us to take a look at it. That way we can maintain the context of the original answers.

Comment: really appreciate it brother! I did create a new question, which is related to this same question but it includes more than 1 object in `data` array. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73095903/compare-one-array-with-a-nested-array-and-push-value-into-a-new-array-in-javascr is really my actual question. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Aaron Np problem! Mark this as the correct answer if it satisfies you for this question. If you can promise that the scope won't change again, I'll check out the new question ;P

Comment: Done! The only change apart from an additional object in `data` in that question is that I no longer need to pass `null` values in place of the `arrayOne` index. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

- Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over each element of *arr1* and return a new array.
- Reassemble the *data* attribute array of each element in the *arr2* array
  using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- When *arr1* traverses, you can get the current element *id*, use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
  to filter the combined *data* array, and return an element array that matches
  the current element *id*.
- Based on the case where the id is not matched, use the [optional chain operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to get the value.
- When returning

  1. if you want to get the element array of the id and
     value attributes, use [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), when it doesn't match, return the original element,
     when it matches, use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), copy the current element
     attribute, and add the *value* attribute
  2. if you only want to get an
     array of matching results, just return the value,
     remember to use the [optional chain operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to convert the unmatched
     value to *null*.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: '110' },
  { id: '202' },
  { id: '259' }
];

const arr2 = [
  { data: [{ value: 'Alpha', id: '001' }] },
  { data: [{ value: 'Bravo', id: '202' }] }
];

const result1 = arr1.map(o1 => {
  const data = arr2.map(o2 => o2.data).flat();
  const value = data.filter(o2 => o2.id === o1.id)[0]?.value;
  return value ? {...o1, value} : o1;
});

const result2 = arr1.map(o1 => {
  const data = arr2.map(o2 => o2.data).flat();
  const value = data.filter(o2 => o2.id === o1.id)[0]?.value;
  return value ?? null;
});

[result1, result2].forEach(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this easy line of code :

```js
const arrayOne = [{  id: '110' }, { id: '202' }, { id: '259' }];

const arrayTwo = [{ data: [{ value: 'Alpha', id: '001' }], }, { data: [{ value: 'Bravo', id: '202' }] }];       

let result = arrayOne.map(el => {
    let found = arrayTwo.find(f => f.data.at(0)?.id == el.id)?.data.at(0)?.value;
    return { id: el.id, value: found ?? null};
});

console.log(result);
```